# Probability that in an endless series of independent Bernoulli trials, the pattern of $101$ will appear infinite times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

What is the probability that in an endless series of independent Bernoulli trials, with probability $p$ for getting $1$ and probability $q=1-p$ for getting $0$, the pattern of $101$ will appear infinite times?

I don't really know how calculate this, but i assume that the probability is $1$.

I mean, if it's not, then it means that in some point, we won't get any $101$ **at all**. I don't know, it sounds impossible.

I tried to see it as: $Y \sim G(pqp)$ = Geometric random variable, where we say that a success is a getting a sequence of $101$, that's with the probability of $pqp$.

Then, $P(Y=k)=(1-pqp)^{k-1}pqp$ implies that the probability that after $k$ times we get the pattern of $101$.

So when $k \to \infty$, $P(Y=k)=0$ meaning that there is not chance that we won't get any $101$ in the future. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\big(1-P(Y=k)\big)}=1-0=1$

What's your thoughts about this manner? Do you think my final answer is correct at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_n$ denote the outcome of the $n$-th Bernoulli trial and define, for $i=1,2,3, \ldots$, the events $$A_i=  \{ X_{3i-2} = 1, X_{3i-1} = 0, X_{3i} =1 \}$$
Notice that the events $A_i$ are independent and $P(A_i) = p^2 (1-p)$. Furthermore, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty p^2 (1-p) = \infty$$
Thus, by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, $P(A_i \text{ infinitely often}) = 1$. Since the $A_i$'s happen infinitely often with probability $1$, so does the sequence $101$, as you conjectured.

Comment: hmm.. Is that ok that the probability above is equal to $\infty?$

We know that $P$ is a "function" that $P: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$, so how is it possible that it'll get values beyond $[0,1]$? (not to mention $\infty$)

Comment: @ryden The quantity $\sum P(A_i)$ is not a probability. Are you familiar with the Borel-Cantelli lemmas?

Comment: we learned those three:
$$$$
1) $P(\Omega)=1$
$$$$
2) $P(A) \geq 0$, for all $A \in \Omega$
$$$$
3) If we have $A_1,A_2,... \in \Sigma$ disjoint in pairs, then $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_i}=\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)$
$$$$

did you mean those?

Comment: @ryden No. Also the domain of $P$ is not $\Omega$, but rather a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Please read this: [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)